# R programms works on R consols and gives errors on Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am making some programms in R to get some plots fro a csv file , and the program in Rstudio giving me error while running , but in the console it works great.

in Rstudio errors like :

```
error in as.posixlt.character(as.character(x) ...) character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

but in R console i don"t see this error and everything works fine

Comment: I doubt this is an Rstudio issue. Would it be possible to show the script you're using? How are you calling the script?

Comment: by clicking on source , the script works fine in R console , and gives me the plot , but in rstudio it gives me this .